# How to dynamically load the SELECT options in html based on value from previous html

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I'm calling a javascript function from html page say "1" to open html page "2" where it has a drop down. Based on the status of the file selected in html page "1" I would like to change the option list in SELECT im showing on page "2". How many ways i can achieve and what is the best practice for this in general. Thanks

Comment: When you change the value on page 1, store it with `localStorage.setItem()`.  When you open page 2 use `localStorage.getItem()` to retrieve the value and set the dropdown on that page.

Comment: Thanks @Archer. got it. but using that value on page 2, how can we dynamically list the values in the dropdown,..?

Comment: What do you mean?  If the dropdown needs to show a different list for each value from page 1 then you're better off ignoring the previous advice I gave, posting the value on page 1 to the server and then the server gives you page 2 with the correct options in the dropdown.

Comment: may be I should have been more specific,.. Im using window.showModalDialog(...) to open the page 2...  not backend call to the server is made,..

Comment: not sure why the question is down voted... :(

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the clarification regarding the use of `window.showModalDialog` because that changes the question.

Comment: You can pass the value in the Url when you open the dialog and then build the dialog page on the server, including the correct values for the dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

1) How many ways? You can:
-load the whole (100% server side) new page and set the selected value at load time 
-load only the area affected (< 100% server side) by the SELECTion (via  javascript/XMLHttpRequest) and set the selected value at runtime via (via javascript)

2) best practice for this in general?
The bottleneck is the internet speed, so better use javascript/XMLHttpRequest.

PS: Your question accepts lots of answers, but those (IMO) cover all the bases. Hope it helps,

Answer (score -1):

[Recommended way]
1. You can pass selected option from Html 1 to a server method. Once you have that in server method then you can either save it in the database or you can directly pass it a Html 2 view and you can load your option list based on a selected option(Assumed you are doing it in MVC).

> You can user jquery to do this very easily.
>    1. First take the value of a select option
>    2. then call `.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )` method and pass the selected option to a controller method
>    3. Then return a second Html page from your controller method.

2.Another option is as mentioned by Archer you can save it in Local storage in a browser from HTML1 using `localStorage.setItem()` method and retrieve it from page 2 using `localStorage.getItem().`

Comment: Thanks Ingale88s. Option 1 is not suitable to this case because Page 1 is not using backend to load page 2. it is directly Page 2. Im more inclined to what Archer has suggested. But still would like to know after getting the value, how to list the options dynamically meaning based on different status I would like to load different set of options,..

Comment: if you use $("my-select").val('').trigger('change')

Comment: Once you have the list of options in an object then you can use $.each(result, function() {
    $("my-select").append($("<option />").val(this.value).text(this.text));
});  this code will go through the list and append an option to your dropdown.